# How to Merge a list of Multiple DataFrames and Tag each Column with a another list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a lisit of DataFrames that come from the census api, i had stored each year pull into a list.

So at the end of my for loop i have a list with dataframes per year and a list of years to go along side the for loop.

The problem i am having is merging all the DataFrames in the list while also taging them with a list of years.

So i have tried using the reduce function, but it looks like it only taking 2 of the 6 Dataframes i have.

concat just adds them to the dataframe with out tagging or changing anything

```
# Dependencies

import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import pprint

import requests
from census import Census

from us import states

# Census
from config import (api_key, gkey)
year = 2012
c = Census(api_key, year)
```

```
for length in range(6):
    c = Census(api_key, year)

    data = c.acs5.get(('NAME', "B25077_001E","B25064_001E",
                          "B15003_022E","B19013_001E"),
                           {'for': 'zip code tabulation area:*'})

    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data_df = data_df.rename(columns={"NAME": "Name",
                                      "zip code tabulation area": "Zipcode",
                                      "B25077_001E":"Median Home Value",
                                     "B25064_001E":"Median Rent",
                                     "B15003_022E":"Bachelor Degrees",
                                     "B19013_001E":"Median Income"})


    data_df = data_df.astype({'Zipcode':'int64'})   




    filtervalue = data_df['Median Home Value']>0
    filtervalue2 = data_df['Median Rent']>0
    filtervalue3 = data_df['Median Income']>0

    cleandata = data_df[filtervalue][filtervalue2][filtervalue3]
    cleandata = cleandata.dropna()


    yearlst.append(year)
    datalst.append(cleandata)
    year += 1
```

so this generates the  two seperate list one with the year and other with dataframe.

So my output came out to either one Dataframe with missing Dataframe entries or it just concatinated all without changing columns.

what im looking for is how to merge all within a list, but datalst[0] to be tagged with yearlst[0] when merging if at all possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for year list, simply [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) year column to data frame. Plus avoid incrementing *year* and have it the iterator column. In fact, consider chaining your process:

```
for year in range(2012, 2019):
    c = Census(api_key, year) 

    data = c.acs5.get(('NAME', "B25077_001E","B25064_001E", "B15003_022E","B19013_001E"), 
                      {'for': 'zip code tabulation area:*'}) 

    cleandata = (pd.DataFrame(data) 
                   .rename(columns={"NAME": "Name", 
                                    "zip code tabulation area": "Zipcode", 
                                    "B25077_001E": "Median_Home_Value", 
                                    "B25064_001E": "Median_Rent", 
                                    "B15003_022E": "Bachelor_Degrees", 
                                    "B19013_001E": "Median_Income"}) 
                   .astype({'Zipcode':'int64'}) 
                   .query('(Median_Home_Value > 0) & (Median_Rent > 0) & (Median_Income > 0)')
                   .dropna()
                   .assign(year_column = year)
                 )

    datalst.append(cleandata)


final_data = pd.concat(datalst, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Follow up question is can i do arthematic on the data frame after i group them. It looks like this currently https://gyazo.com/77ff9a29aafe1cce09e1d7e38fedb917

like i want to take for each Name the first and last year and calculate the change in %

Comment: Certainly doable. Please ask a new question with [mcve] including data, attempted code, and desired result.